# Authorization happens before authentication after migrating to .net core 3.1

Tags: migration, authorization, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

After migrating from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1, and after taking some time to fix all the bugs depending on documentations, after running the app, the authorization method get's hit before it requires the user to be authenticated.

I am using OpenId Connect with AD FS for authentication and a custom method called "PermissionGranted" for authorization. And this method get's hit before it requires for the user to be authenticated.

This is the code of my Startup.cs file:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ConfigSettings settings;
    private readonly GetSettings configSettings;
    private readonly MyMemoryCache myMemoryCache;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configSettings = new GetSettings();
        settings = configSettings.getSettings();
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = env;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        myMemoryCache = new MyMemoryCache();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.FromLogContext()
           .WriteTo.Console()
           .WriteTo.File(settings.LogFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
           .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration(settings.AppInsightsConnection), TelemetryConverter.Events)
           .CreateLogger();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
        services.AddSingleton(settings);
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
           .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
           {
               options.AccessDeniedPath = "/users/denied";
           })
           .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
               options.MetadataAddress = settings.MetadataAddress;
               options.ClientId = settings.ClientId;
               options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
               options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
               options.SignedOutRedirectUri = settings.PostLogoutUri;
               options.SaveTokens = true;
               options.UseTokenLifetime = true;

               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidAudience = settings.ClientId,
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidIssuer = settings.Issuer,
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   RequireExpirationTime = true
               };

               options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
               {
                   OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                   {
                       context.HandleResponse();
                       context.Response.Redirect("/Login");

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   },
                   OnTicketReceived = context =>
                   {
                       // Configuration to make the Authentication cookie persistent for 8 hours (after 8 hours it expires and the user has to re-authenticate)
                       context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                       context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(8);

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   }
               };

               options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
               {
                   context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               };
           });

        Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
           .UseSqlServer(config => config
           .ConnectionString(settings.ConnectionString)
           .TableName("AuditEvents")
           .IdColumnName("EventId")
           .JsonColumnName("AuditData")
           .LastUpdatedColumnName("LastUpdatedDate"));

        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(settings.AppInsightsConnection);

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        // Use NewtonsoftJson and custom date format
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;  // Make the session cookie essential
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Permissions", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context => PermissionGranted(context)));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<PasswordManagerContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(settings.ConnectionString));

        services.AddSingleton<MyMemoryCache>();

        services.AddPaging(options =>
        {
            options.ViewName = "PagerUI";
            options.HtmlIndicatorDown = " <span>&darr;</span>";
            options.HtmlIndicatorUp = " <span>&uarr;</span>";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");
        });
        ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices;
    }
```

According to official docs, the order of these:

```
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
 app.UseEndpoints
```

matters but in my code they are ordered correctly.

What could be missing or what could possibly be wrong in the configuration?

Thanks in advance